# Whats is cob-app-name and channel-cob-app-name in yodlee fastlink2 url?

Tags: yodlee

I am looking for explanation on what is cob-app-name and channel-cob-app-name in yodlee's document but could not find it. Has anyone else figured this out?

Looks like the format for Fastlink 2.0 is this-

https:///authenticate//?

But I can not find info on cob-app-name and channel-cob-app-name. Is there any other API that gives this info?

Comment: Sorry the URL format is [link] https://<node_domain>/authenticate/<cob_app_name>/?<channel-cob-app-name>

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Cob_app_name is the cobrand app name. It is the name of Yodlee's customer.

channel-cob-app-name is the name of the channel which Yodlee assigns to that customer.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik